# Birthdate + Gender calculations using identity Number - PHP/ Html/MySqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am a new, "trying to be"  PHP Html and MySqli programmer coming from Ms Access and VB background. Can somebody please assist,  as I am stuck and sweating with these calculations.

Example Identity number = 63021854485519

- The Birthdate from this =  dd/mm/yyyy = 18/02/1963
- The 7th digit indicates male or female ie 0-4 = female and 5-9 = male , So
- this person's Id No indicates its a Male as 7th digit is 5 (between 5-9)

In VB to calculate birthdate from ID No I use ---> `DOB=Mid([idno],5,2) & "/" & Mid([idno],3,2) & "/" & Mid([idno],1,2)` Require as dd/mm/yyyy.

In VB to calculate Gender I use --> `Gender=IIf(Mid([idno],7,1) Between 0 And 4,"Female","Male")`.

I use the following similar input text boxes on my form. How do I adjust it for birthdate and gender respectively please?

```html
 <tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="name">birthdate</label></div></td>
<td><input name="birthdate" type="text" class="input" size="20"  /></td>
</tr>
```

```php
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
    //include("connect.php");   
    $msg = "";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {   
        $idno = $_POST["idno"];
        $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        $birthdate = $_POST["birthdate"];
        $age = $_POST["age"];


        //++++
        $idno = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $idno);
        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $gender);
        $birthdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $birthdate);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $age);





        {
            //$msg = "Sorry...This email already exist...";
        }
        //else
        {

            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO tblpersons (gender,idno,birthdate,age)VALUES ('$gender','$idno','$birthdate','$age')");

            if($query)
            {
                $msg = "Thank You! you are now registered.";
            }
        }
    }
?>


<!doctype html>
<html>



<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
<title>Race Registration Form by Zululand Multisport</title>

label
{
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.input
{
    padding:5px;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:18px;
}
input[type=submit]
{
    padding:5px;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#999;
    border:2px solid black;
    color:#FFF;
}
fieldset
{
    width: 500px;
}
fieldset legend
{
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#999;
    border:2px solid black;
    color:#FFF;
}
.error
{
    color:red;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }

</script>

<body>

<form method="post" action="">

</tr>
<td height="23"></td>
<td><div align="left">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Home" />
</div></td>
</tr>
<fieldset>


<legend>Registration Form for Personal Details  -  (&copy; Neels Ferreira - 2017) </legend>
<?php echo $todaydate = date('d/m/Y');?>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table width="600" border="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">

<tr>
<td colspan="1" align="center" class="error"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="name">idno</label></div></td>
<td><input name="idno" type="text" class="input" size="20" onKeyDown="limitText(this,13);" 
onKeyUp="limitText(this,13);"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="name">birthdate</label></div></td>
<td><input name="birthdate" type="date" class="input" size="20"  /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="name">gender</label></div></td>
<td><input name="gender" type="date" class="input" size="10"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-weight: bold"><div align="right"><label for="name">age (31/12)</label></div></td>
<td><input name="age" type="text" class="input" size="10" /></td>
</tr>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<td height="23"></td>
<td><div align="left">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Personal Details and Continue!" />
</div></td>
</tr>



</body>

</html>
```

```html
CREATE TABLE `tblpersons` (
  `entriesid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Idno` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `age` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblpersons`
--

INSERT INTO `tblpersons` (`entriesid`, `Idno`, `gender`, `age`, `birthdate`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(121,  '6302185142311', 'male',  '32', '1963-02-18','2016-11-26 22:10:53');
```

Please assist with PHP and where I add it to this HTML code.

Comment: there's no db code here making this question both unclear and too broad; so, where's your mysql code?

Answer (score 1):

OK, you can do it like this.

1.Create `helpers.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Returns birth date from identity
 *
 * @param string $identity Identity string
 * 
 * @return \DateTime
 */
function getBirthdateFromIdentity($identity) {
    // substring identity to get bday
    $date = substr($identity, 0, 6);

    // use built-in DateTime object to work with dates
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('ymd', $date);
    $now  = new \DateTime();

    // compare birth date with current date: 
    // if it's bigger bd was in previous century
    if ($date > $now) {
        $date->modify('-100 years');
    }

    return $date;
}

/**
 * Returns gender string from identity
 *
 * @param string $identity Identity string
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function getGenderFromIdentity($identity) {
    // substring gender data and convert it to int
    $gender = (int) substr($identity, 6, 1);
    return ($gender >= 0 && $gender <= 4) ? 'Female' : 'Male';
}

/**
 * Returns age from birthdate (on 31 December of the current year)
 *
 * @param \DateTime $birthdate Birth date
 * 
 * @return int
 */
function getAgeFromBirthday(\DateTime $birthdate) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $interval = $date->diff($birthdate);
    return $interval->y;
}
```

2.Include `helpers.php` to your main file:

```
<?php
require_once("helpers.php");
require_once("connect.php");

$success = '';
$error   = '';

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{   
    $idno      = trim($_POST["idno"]);
    $gender    = trim($_POST["gender"]);
    $birthdate = trim($_POST["birthdate"]);
    $age       = trim($_POST["age"]);

    // identity number is mandatory field
    if (!empty($idno)) {
        // if gender is not set - use gender from identity number
        if (empty($gender)) {
            $gender = getGenderFromIdentity($idno);
        }

        // if birthdate is set - try to parse it from format which is mentioned in html form
        if (!empty($birthdate)) {
            $birthdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $birthdate);
        }

        // if birthdate is not valid or not set - use bday from identity number
        if (empty($birthdate)) {
            $birthdate = getBirthdateFromIdentity($idno);
        }

        // if age is not set - use age from identity number
        if (empty($age)) {
            $age = getAgeFromBirthday($birthdate);
        }

        $idno      = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $idno);
        $gender    = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $gender);
        $birthdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $birthdate->format('Y-m-d'));
        $age       = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $age);

        $query = sprintf(
            "INSERT INTO tblpersons (gender,idno,birthdate,age) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%d')", 
            $gender, 
            $idno, 
            $birthdate, 
            $age
        );
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

        if ($query) {
            $success = "Thank You! you are now registered.";
        } else {
            $error = "Sorry, your request can't be processed.";
        }
    } else {
        $error = "Please, fill the form";
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Race Registration Form by Zululand Multisport</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
label
{
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.input
{
    padding:5px;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:18px;
}
input[type=submit]
{
    padding:5px;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#999;
    border:2px solid black;
    color:#FFF;
}
fieldset
{
    width: 500px;
}
fieldset legend
{
    padding:2px;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#999;
    border:2px solid black;
    color:#FFF;
}
.success
{
    color:green;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:16px;
}
.error
{
    color:red;
    font-family:Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    font-size:16px;
}
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
    }
}
</script>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">

</tr>
<td height="23"></td>
<td><div align="left">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Home" />
</div></td>
</tr>

<fieldset>
<legend>Registration Form for Personal Details  -  (&copy; Neels Ferreira - 2017) </legend>
<?php echo $todaydate = date('d/m/Y');?>

<table width="600" border="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
<?php if (!empty($success)): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="success"><?php echo $success; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (!empty($error)): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center" class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>

<tr>
<td><div align="right"><label for="idno">idno</label></div></td>
<td><input id="idno" name="idno" type="text" class="input" size="20" onKeyDown="limitText(this,13);" onKeyUp="limitText(this,13);"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right"><label for="name">birthdate</label></div></td>
<td><input name="birthdate" type="date" class="input" size="20"  /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right"><label for="name">gender</label></div></td>
<td><input name="gender" type="date" class="input" size="10"  /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div align="right"><label for="name">age (31/12)</label></div></td>
<td><input name="age" type="text" class="input" size="10" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td height="23"></td>
<td><div align="left"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Personal Details and Continue!" /></div></td>
</tr>

</table>
</fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Couple of things I would like to note:

1. Form validation: you should design a proper rules to validate your form.
2. Database abstraction layer (DBAL): i suggest you to look at DBAL libraries like Doctrine DBAL to optimize the code for interacting with DB
3. Microframeworks: in your case you don't need a big framework like Laravel, but microframework like Slim, Silex or Lumen can speed up development process significantly. Take a look one of them.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. Sorry i am still very stupid with this PHP but i usually learn fast after a few examples. Do i create a separate php file and save it in the same folder and call it from there ,OR where do i create this helper functions to get birthdate / gender from ID.

Comment: It depends on how you render your HTML form. Sure, you can create a new php file for these helpers function but you should not to forget to include this file into the place where you render your HTML.
If you can provide more details on your project structure it will be easier to decide where is to place these helper functions.

Comment: I have added my code and create table code. The complete code with all the fields populate the database without errors. This is a condensed version. Pls shout if more info is needed

Comment: Another question based on this birthdate created here that i want to ask later in different Question session to finish this project off,  is to calculate the age as on 31 December of the current year.That is way the birthdate needs to be in a dd/mm/yyyy format to calculate the age

Comment: Thank you, thank you , u are a star. I have been struggling for a week now. I have 2 applications in mind to use this method - cycling registration as  seen here and a patient dispensing application. There is just one small problem - i get this error on the last line of my main file where it ends as </html>  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\rtweb\register.php on line 140". the Localhost is open and working i tested it. Looking forward to hearing about the solution

Comment: I've also added few things: 1) `$error` and `$success` variables - if form was submitted successfully than message will be shown with green text; if there was an error - with red text.
2) you had typo in your javascript `limitText` function - you forget to close braces - ixed it
3) moved `<style>` & `<script>` tags to the `<head>`
4) you have duplicating `jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js` dependency - removed duplication

Comment: Thx for all that trouble its appreciated. I have learned so much in the last 12hrs now. Will follow your advice on DBAL etc. Sorry to be on your case again. When adding an IdNo can one populate the birthdate, gender and age in realtime  in textboxes ?  i got "Notice: Use of undefined constant query - assumed 'query' in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\rtweb\register.php on line 49  =          $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, query); I fixed it using $query. thx

Comment: > When adding an IdNo can one populate the birthdate, gender and age in realtime in textboxes ?
You need to use javascript for it to do it in realtime

Comment: If my answer was helpfull do not hesitate vote for it )

Comment: Kriv i noticed the age is not calculated as of the last day of the year. ie if persons birthdate still has to take place after today but before 31 Dec, then it must subtract (31/12/"current yr") - (birthdate) = age as of 31/12   If the birthdate is ie 1994/12/25,  then person must be 22 today as a max for 2016. Any suggestions please